# How do I show the columns of the grid of Bourbon Neat?

Tags: css, sass, grid-layout, bourbon, neat

In my CSS file apply the commands of Bourbon Neat and not show columns in html file, if show the result of apply but not show columns.

```
.container{
    @include outer-container;
    @include span-columns(2 of 8, table);
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}
```

When show the css generated for sass not show background property of Bourbon Neat columns.

Comment: Could you also post generated CSS and target HTML?

Answer (score 14):

The important thing is to both set `$visual-grid: true;` and define your breakpoints before your line `@import "neat";`

From https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat#using-neat:

> The visual grid reflects the changes applied to the grid via the
>   new-breakpoint() mixin, as long as the media contexts are defined
>   *before* importing Neat.

Whether or not you choose to use a `_grid-settings.scss` file (as the docs recommend) is up to you. But in order to see the visual grid at all you definitely need to set `$visual-grid: true;` before importing neat. And in order for the visual grid to behave responsively, you also need to define your breakpoints before importing neat.

Comment: Thank you. The downside of using a variable as opposed to a mixin to show grids.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, just adding "$visual-grid: true;" in the container won't work. Or at least it doesn't work for me. However, adding a "_getting-settings.scss" file with the following settings in the file worked for me:

```
$visual-grid: true;
$visual-grid-color: yellow;
$visual-grid-index: front;
$visual-grid-opacity: 0.5;
```

The documentation isn't very clear where $visual-gridL should go, so it's hard to tell if that is as the developers intended. I think they need to provide better examples in this case.

Answer (score 1):

in container, you need to add

```
  $visual-grid: true;
```

This should show the grid column backgrounds for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a file like below ( adjust settings to your own requirements ).
   *This file overwrites the neat default settings that are in
   `_visual-grid.scss` in neat's settings directory.*
2. Add an import to the file you just created the line **Before** ( after will not work ) you import the main neat file into your main project SCSS file.

**_neatsettings.scss**

```
// Neat Settings

$visual-grid: true;
$visual-grid-color: #faa;
$visual-grid-index: front;
```

Comment: How does this add anything over the existing answers?

Comment: I would think it's more clear and more authoritative. The existing answers didn't really help me that much when I was working it out myself that's why I put the answer up

Comment: Ok, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18707737/1652962) shows which settings you need to use and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18709461/1652962) clarifies that the variables have to be before you import neat.  You're just rehashing existing answers.

Comment: that answer a) implies that you have to add visual-grid to the container and b) doesn't specify that the settings has to be added before the neat import and also includes some confusion `it's hard to tell if that is as the developers intended.` plus there's a typo as far as I can tell ... It didn't fix my problem anyway at the time as I spent an hour or so trying to figure it out